# Is there a way to see ONLY your communities questions in the Stack Exchange home?

Tags: support, homepage

### New here

Hello to everyone. I've created my Stack Exchange account just now and I joined some communities. When I go to https://stackexchange.com/ I have noticed that I can only see a list of the hot questions and real-time ones, completely disregarding the communities I have personally chosen.

This is what I see in my home page:

[![Example of what I see][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNika.png

Is there a way to show **only** the questions I'm interested in?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Click on "Filtered Questions".

There are default filters for "My sites" (i.e. only the sites you have joined) and "Favorite Tags" for any favourite tags you have set. Click on the filter to view the questions. I believe it will remember the last filter selected so that every time you click on "Filtered Questions" it will show the last fiter you selected.

> [image]

You can also set up your own filters based on specific tags and sites. You can save these filters to view whenever you like and even get email updates for the filters. Simply click on "New filter" and set up the filter as you'd like:

> [image]

Comment: Thank you a lot! Actually, I've already clicked on "Filter Questions" and "My sites" but I saw only Stack Overflow questions and I was confused. Then I realized that it is a community **bombed** with questions and that's why it was the only one to appear. I've created my own filter now, that's nice.

Comment: Yes, Stack Overflow far outweighs most sites in numbers! Probably best to filter everything else and view SO on its own.